# converting dictionaries

Tags: python

this is my dictionary

```
dict = {'apple':'der Apfel', 'ant':'die Ameise', 'asparagus':'der Spargel'}
```

i would like to get an output:

```
dictionary for a
apple: der Apfel
ant:die Ameise
asparagus:der Spargel
```

I am new to dictionaries
please help

i tried doing

```
def tutorial8_part2():
  dict = {'apple':'der Apfel', 'ant':'die Ameise', 'asparagus':'der Spargel'}
  dictList = dict.items()
  for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    temp = []
    aKey = key
    aValue = value
    temp.append(aKey)
    temp.append(aValue)
    dictList.append(temp)
    print dictList.append(temp)
```

but its not working

Comment: I have no clue what your code is attempting.

Comment: The reason it's not working is that the .append() method for lists changes the list, but *returns* `None`. After you've run `dictList.append(temp)`, `temp` is added to dictList, and you can just `print dictList`

Comment: Do you just want to print key, value pairs? Does order matter to you?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to print out each key and value pair in a long line, you can do this:

```
dict = {'apple':'der Apfel', 'ant':'die Ameise', 'asparagus':'der Spargel'}
for key, value in dict.items():
  print key + ':', value,
print
```

The output will probably not be in the same order as when you created the dictionary. Iterating through a dictionary doesn't guarantee any particular order, unless you specifically sort the keys, for example with the sorted() built-in function:

```
for key, value in sorted(dict_.items()):  
    print "{0}: {1}".format(key, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to iterate through a dictionary, to print key and value pairs:

```
>>> dict_ = {'apple':'der Apfel', 'ant':'die Ameise', 'asparagus':'der Spargel'}
>>> for k,v in dict_.iteritems():
...   print k, ':', v
... 
ant : die Ameise
asparagus : der Spargel
apple : der Apfel
```

In one-line using a generator expression:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in dict_.iteritems())
ant: die Ameise
asparagus: der Spargel
apple: der Apfel
```

As a side note, avoid using `dict` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Will this do what you are trying to do?

(EDIT: updated to the new output format)

```
my_dict = {'apple':'der Apfel', 'ant':'die Ameise', 'asparagus':'der Spargel'}

print 'dictionary for a'
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
     print '%s:%s' % (k, v)
```

yields:

```
dictionary for a
ant:die Ameise
asparagus:der Spargel
apple:der Apfel
```

Note that this order is different from the one you posted, but the question didn't make it clear if order mattered.

As correctly suggested by @wim, it's better not to use `dict` as a variable name.